# upload de arquivo com erro no retorno json

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

Estou fazendo o upload de um arquivo com jquery+ajax usando o plugin jquery form plugin.

O processamento do formulário esta tudo ok, o arquivo sobe e os dados são gravados no banco.
O problema esta no retorno com a resposta em json. Esta imprimindo a string de resposta.

View:

```
$("#salvar-fcei").click(function () {
        // bind form using ajaxForm 
        $('#jsonForm').ajaxForm({
            // dataType identifies the expected content type of the server response 
            dataType: 'json',
            // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
            // has been received 
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.mensagem == 'ok') {
                    $(".modal-title").html("Cadastro realizado com sucesso!");
                    $(".modal-text").html("O gestor foi adicionado com sucesso ao Projeto.");
                    $("#modal").addClass('modal-success');
                    $("#modal").modal();
                } else {
                    $(".modal-title").html("Ops! Verifique os erros abaixo");
                    $(".modal-text").html(response.mensagem);
                    $("#modal").addClass('modal-warning');
                    $("#modal").modal();
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

A tag form:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="frm-fcei" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' action="<?php echo base_url('projeto/add_fcei'); ?>">
```

O Controller:

```
function add_fcei(){
    $response = $this->model_projeto->add_fcei();
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

O Model

```
function add_fcei() {
    $config['upload_path'] = './fcei';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['file_name'] = 'FCEI-'.$this->input->post('id_projeto').'-'.$this->input->post('numero');

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ($this->upload->do_upload('arquivo')){
        $data['id_projeto'] = $this->input->post('id_projeto');
        $data['numero'] = $this->input->post('numero');
        $data['dt_emissao'] = $this->input->post('dt_emissao');
        $data['arquivo'] = $this->upload->data('file_name');
        $data['dt_cadastro'] = date('Y-m-d');
        $data['status'] = '1';
        if ($this->db->insert('cadastro_fcei',$data)){
            $response = ['mensagem'=>'ok'];
        } else{
            $response = ['mensagem'=>'Não foi possí­vel cadastrar no banco de dados. Arquivo foi salvo.'];
        }
    } else{
        $response = ['mensagem'=>$this->upload->display_errors()];
    }
    return $response;
}
```

Quando faço o envio do form ele imprime na tela array

```
{'mensagem':'ok'}
```

Comment: Olá Fabrício, você poderia esclarecer o que você quer fazer? A saída parece estar de acordo com o seu código, isso é `$response = ['mensagem'=>'ok'];`. O que exatamente você quer que aconteça?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defina um cabeçalho para o seu retorno.

```
   function add_fcei(){
        //define um cabeçalho
        header('Content-Type: application/json');
        $response = $this->model_projeto->add_fcei();
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
```

Lembrando que `echo` no *controller* não é uma boa prática. O mais adequado seria criar uma *view* para seus retornos JSON.

Comment: A questão era o retorno do json para a view. Depois consegui resolver o problema. Obrigado.